# Singular values of product of three rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have a rectangular matrix $Q\in\mathbb R^{p\times n}$, where $p<n$, and a symmetric (but not necessarily positive definite) matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Is it true that $\sigma_p(QAQ^T) \geq \sigma_p(Q)^2\sigma_n(A)$?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(